# How to find out if an Ethereum address is a contract?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

An address in Solidity can be an account or a contract (or other things, such as a transaction). When I have a variable x, holding an address, how can I test if it is a contract or not?

(Yes, I've read the [chapter on types](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html) in the doc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: Solidity has changed since this answer was first written, @manuel-aráoz has the correct answer.

There is no way in solidity to check if an address is a contract. One of the goals of Ethereum is for humans and smart contracts to both be treated equally. This leads into a future where smart contracts interact seamlessly with humans and other contracts. It might change in the future , but for now an arbitrary address is ambiguous.

Comment: The gas consumed by sending to contract is utterly different than the gas consumed by sending to an address.  If there were a goal to treat those two things in the same way, there couldn't be a gas distinction.

Answer (score 63):

Yes you can, by using some EVM assembly code to get the address' code size:

```
function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
  uint size;
  assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
  return size > 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's some [info](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14015/using-evm-assembly-to-get-the-address-code-size/14016#14016) on how this function works

Comment: This code is dangerous and no longer advisable as it is [hackable](http://web.archive.org/web/20190105222409/https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide) because EXTCODESIZE returns 0 in a contract's constructor.

Answer (score 33):

### The top-voted answer with the `isContract` function that uses EXTCODESIZE was discovered to be hackable.

The function will return false if it is invoked from a contract's constructor (because the contract has not been deployed yet).

The code should be used very carefully, if at all, to avoid security hacks such as:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190105222409/https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide))

To [repeat](http://web.archive.org/web/20180128183802/https://medium.com/@matthewdif/mechanism-design-security-in-smart-contracts-87f08555b38b):

**Do not use the EXTCODESIZE check to prevent smart contracts from calling a function. This is not foolproof, it can be subverted by a constructor call, due to the fact that while the constructor is running, EXTCODESIZE for that address returns 0.**

**See [sample code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64340/42) for a contract that tricks EXTCODESIZE to return 0.**

---

#### Checking if a caller is a contract

If you want to make sure that an EOA is calling your contract, a simple way is `require(msg.sender == tx.origin)`. However, preventing a contract is an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/683) with [security](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/security-considerations.html#tx-origin) and [interoperability](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin) considerations.

`require(msg.sender == tx.origin)` will need revisiting when account abstraction is implemented.

#### Checking if a callee is a contract

As @Luke points out in a comment, there is **no** general on-chain way to find out about a callee.  If you want to "call" an address, there's no general way to find out if that address is a contract, EOA, or an address that a new contract can be deployed on, or if it's a CREATE2 address.

One non-general way that works for some callees: you can have a mapping on-chain that stores addresses of known EOAs or contracts. (Just remember that for an address without any on-chain history, you can't know if it's an EOA or an address that a contract can be deployed on.)

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that `require(msg.sender == tx.origin)` only detects if the caller of a function is an EOA, it can't be used to detect if any other third-party contract is an EOA (such as a contract that you want to call from your own function).

Comment: @LukeHutchison Upvoted, great point! Added the caller and callee case; happy to hear from you if I missed some things or you have other suggestions.

Comment: For completeness you could add that extcodesize is now abstracted away to `<address>.code.size` in solidity (no assembly needed). People need to recognize this form too. (I might have the syntax wrong, I'm not near a computer right now.)

Answer (score 14):

This isn't something you can query from within a contract using Solidity, but if you were just wanting to know whether an address holds contract code or not, you can check using your geth console or similar with eg:

```
  > eth.getCode("0xbfb2e296d9cf3e593e79981235aed29ab9984c0f")
```

with the hex string (here `0xbfb2e296d9cf3e593e79981235aed29ab9984c0f`) as the address you wish to query. This will return the bytecode stored at that address.

You can also use a blockchain scanner to find the source code of the contract at that address, for example [the ecsol library](https://etherscan.io/address/0x28dcd428e8125990f9e5fe1b82db0e3ed240711c#code) as shown on [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/).

Answer (score 3):

From openzeppeling [Address.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Address.sol) library, it has this function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
    // This method relies on extcodesize/address.code.length, which returns 0
    // for contracts in construction, since the code is only stored at the end
    // of the constructor execution.

    return account.code.length > 0;
}
```

> `isContract` will return false for the following types of addresses:
>
> - an externally-owned account
> - a contract in construction
> - an address where a contract will be created
> - an address where a contract lived, but was destroyed

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use nodejs to confirm, you can do this:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3')

// make sure you are running geth locally
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

is_contract = async function(address) {
    res = await web3.eth.getCode(address)
    return res.length > 5
}

is_contract('your address').then(console.log)
```

Comment: I don't think it makes much of a difference, but I'm curious as to why you went with `return res.length > 5`? If it's not a Smart contract shouldn't `res` be `0x`, meaning `res.length > 2` should work just as well? 

I guess you can also test for `res.startsWith("0x6080604052")`?

Answer (score -1):

What you can do, granted you have the information at hand.
If the transactions sender address was null or unoccupied then you can tell if the address is a contract account or an EOA (externally owned account).
i.e. when sending a create contract transaction on the network then the receive address in the transaction is null/not used.

Reference from github:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions

Hope this helps.

Comment: This link is clearly outdated. It's 2021, this answer is from 2016.

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking whether **the caller** is an EOA rather than a contract:

Short answer:

```
require(tx.origin == msg.sender);
```

tx.origin is a reference of the original address who initiates this serial function call, while msg.sender is the address who directly calls the target function. Which means, tx.origin must be a human, msg.sender can be a contract or human. Thus, if someone calls you from a contract, then the msg.sender is a contract address which is different from tx.origin.

I know most contracts may use @Manuel Aráoz's code, which works in most cases. But if you call a function within the constructor of a contract, extcodesize will return 0 which fails the isContract check.

NOTE: DON'T use tx.origin under other circumstances if you are not clear about what it represents because .

Comment: this means that direct user is calling the function. this is one way of mitigating reentrancy attack because if `(tx.origin == msg.sender)` means there is not a chain of function calls