# How to detect if an Ethereum address is an ERC20 token contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

If I only get an Ethereum address from the input, is there a way to find out whether it matches the [ERC20](https://www.google.com/search?q=erc20+standard&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr) token standard?

Comment: Please post what you have tried already. Is this intended to work on-chain (inside a smart contract) or off chain (maybe using web3js)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ERC165](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/165) tackles this problem, but, unfortunately, most ERC20 implementations don't support it (as of Nov 2018, at least OpenZeppelin [doesn't](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/issues/1073)). This means that you could try calling the [supportsInterface](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/introspection/ERC165.sol#L36) function, but it would revert anyway and you'd rather complicate things.

Nevertheless, here's how it's defined in [ERC721](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol):

```
bytes4 private constant _InterfaceId_ERC721 = 0x80ac58cd;
/*
 * 0x80ac58cd ===
 *   bytes4(keccak256('balanceOf(address)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('ownerOf(uint256)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('approve(address,uint256)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('getApproved(uint256)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('setApprovalForAll(address,bool)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('isApprovedForAll(address,address)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) ^
 *   bytes4(keccak256('safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)'))
 */
```

Although it's not guaranteed for all implementations to define the interface id, there's a higher chance it will work in the case of ERC721, given the fact the community agreed on applying ERC165 right from the get-go. If the return value of the query below is true, then it means you have a compliant contract, otherwise just revert the transaction.

```
// you can call this in your contracts
IERC721(contractAddress).supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd)
```

Also, a useful resource for manually checking the `bytes4` of a given method is [4byte.directory](https://www.4byte.directory)

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking about off-chain, so use these functions:

```
getContract(url, smartContractAddress){
    const Web3Eth = require('web3-eth');

    const abi_ = this.getABI();
    const web3Eth = new Web3Eth(Web3Eth.givenProvider || url);
    return new web3Eth.Contract(abi_, smartContractAddress);
}

async getERCtype(contract){
    const is721 = await contract.methods.supportsInterface('0x80ac58cd').call();
    if(is721){
        return "ERC721";
    }
    const is1155 = await contract.methods.supportsInterface('0xd9b67a26').call();
    if(is1155){
        return "ERC1155";
    }
    return undefined;
}

getABI(){
    return [         
        {"constant":true,"inputs": [
                {"internalType":"bytes4","name": "","type": "bytes4"}],
            "name": "supportsInterface",
            "outputs": [{"internalType":"bool","name": "","type": "bool"}],
            "payable": false,"stateMutability":"view","type": "function"}         
    ];
}
```

like this:

```
const contract = getContract(url, smartContractAddress);
const type = await getERCtype(contract);
console.log(type);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible ways to achieve this. One possible quick and dirty solution is to check if a ERC20 function exists on the contract address by calling the following:

```
eth.call({to:contractAddress, data:web3.sha3("balanceOf(address)")})
```

A non-ERC20 will return a 'null' `0x` hex response whereas an ERC20 will give you a 32byte `uint`, in this case 0 but if you provide an address in the data then it will give you the actual token balance for that address.

This is not a guaranteed way of determining a contract is ERC20 since other contracts may expose the same function, however it is a quick and easy check. You could add additional calls on `totalSupply()` etc. for more confirmation.

Comment: I am thinking what is eth here?

Comment: @MrHash I think the OP was asking for a way to do this in solidity.

Answer (score 0):

the question states that given an Ethereum address, is this an Ethereum contract address or not?

First thing, you have to decide if this address is a contract address or an externally owned account address. [How to find out if an Ethereum address is a contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644395/how-to-find-out-if-an-ethereum-address-is-a-contract)

If it is a contract address, then you can only get the bytecode that is stored in the blockchain. Now you have to reverse engineer the bytecode to get the contract functions but this is almost impossible. There are some decompilers but they are not perfectly creating the contract code from the bytecode.

`ERC165` just checks if the current contract signature supports the given interfaceId or not. Since you have only ethereum address, this will not help in this question.