# How to check if Ethereum address is valid in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, web3js

Is there a way to check if the ethereum address is valid in solidity? I think I might have found a way in web3js library on utils, but want to know if this method is possible on solidity.

And how can I use solidity to know the difference between account addresses and smart contract address?

Comment: The EVM will check and fail if any value set to an address function argument is not an address.
You can also use tests like  
    `require(anAddress == address(anAddress),"Invalid address");`

Comment: What do you mean by a valid address? About the contract addresses you can read there https://stackoverflow.com/q/37644395/7450049

Answer (score 2):

> And how can I use solidity to know the difference between account addresses and smart contract address ?

You can use `EXTCODESIZE` opcode.

```
function isContract(address _a) public returns (bool) {
  uint size;
  assembly {
    size := extcodesize(_a)
  }
  return size > 0
}
```