# How to correctly use tokenReceived method in ERC223 and what is third paramter of the new transfer function

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to create my own ERC223 token. There is not much information online on how to use new functions in ERC223 or I just don't understand it. Github of ERC223 says to implement the IERC223Recipient contract to handle cases when tokens are sent to a contract.

```
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes calldata _data) external override returns (bool)
    {
        require(_value > 0);

        if(isContract(_to)) 
        {
            IERC223Recipient receiver = IERC223Recipient(_to);
            receiver.tokenReceived(msg.sender, _value, _data);
        }

        balances[msg.sender] = SafeMath.sub(balances[msg.sender], _value);
        balances[_to] = SafeMath.add(balances[_to], _value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        emit TransferData(_data);

        return true; 
    }
```

I am not quite sure what _data is in this case. I watched some videos online and they say that this is bytes of a function. I don't understand which function and where to get it.

Once tokenReceived is called this happens:

```
    struct ERC223TransferInfo
    {
        address token_contract;
        address sender;
        uint256 value;
        bytes   data;
    }
    
    ERC223TransferInfo private tkn;
        
    /**
    * @dev Standard ERC223 function that will handle incoming token transfers.
    *
    * @param _from  Token sender address.
    * @param _value Amount of tokens.
    * @param _data  Transaction metadata.
    */
    function tokenReceived(address _from, uint _value, bytes memory _data) public virtual
    {
        /**
         * @dev Note that inside of the token transaction handler the actual sender of token transfer is accessible via the tkn.sender variable
         * (analogue of msg.sender for Ether transfers)
         * 
         * tkn.value - is the amount of transferred tokens
         * tkn.data  - is the "metadata" of token transfer
         * tkn.token_contract is most likely equal to msg.sender because the token contract typically invokes this function
        */
        tkn.token_contract = msg.sender;
        tkn.sender         = _from;
        tkn.value          = _value;
        tkn.data           = _data;
        
        // ACTUAL CODE
    }
```

where tnk is struct above. The developer provides the code and leaves the // ACTUAL CODE comment that confuses me a lot.

I hope it is not a dumb question. I am very stuck on how to use the new ERC223 functions

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In ethereum smart contracts, if `receive` or `fallback` functions are not defined, sending ether to this contract will fail and you will lose the tokens. `ERC223` will make sure that contract that you are sending funds is capable of receiving funds.

Another use case is to make sure that account addresses (externally owned accounts) are executing `mint`, `transfer` or `burn` functions. Because those functions should not be executed by contract addresses. So this function `if(isContract(_to))` in your contract is checking if the `to` address is a contract address or not. this is done by low level solidity function `extcodesize`. [How to find out if an Ethereum address is a contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644395/how-to-find-out-if-an-ethereum-address-is-a-contract)

`_data` is metadata that you want to pass. it can be anything. You can leave it blank by passing "". Or you could pass `msg.data`

> msg.data is the raw data that's sent in the transaction. It's an
> encoding of the function selector and then any parameters that you're
> passing to that function.